# C# and SQL Server - connect to two or more databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, class, connection

I need to connect two databases on one screen using a DB class. A dropdownlist gets information from a database and a gridview gets its information from another database.

I'm working with a DB class and Datasource class.

I do not know how to work with her correctly, and I do not want to do anything improvised.

Code call:

```
DataSource.Open();

public static class DataSource
{
    public static void Open()
    {
        DB.Open();
    }
}

public static OleDbConnection Connection { get; internal set; }

public static bool Open()
{
    try
    {
        if (Connection != null) if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) return true;

        Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrConnection);
        Connection.Open();
        return (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open);
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Works for one database only.

To use it in two databases I have to close one of them before and this generates several trips to the databases.

Thanks!

Comment: You need an OleDbConnection for each database you want to connect to. I'd suggest two classes (one for each database) though

Comment: Also: why are you using `OleDbConnection` for talking to SQL Server? You should use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instead ....